# Testing for equality in two objects with nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have two objects that I am attempting to compare to see if their content is the same. The function I am writing should have these two objects equal true, however, I am struggling with how to sort these so I can test for equal content (it's out of order). How would I solve this?

```
const obj1 = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 27,
  description: [{
    eyes: 'blue',
    hair: 'brown'
  }]
} 

const obj2 = {
  age: 27,
  name: 'Sam',
  description: [{
    hair: 'brown',
    eyes: 'blue'
  }]
}
```

Comment: Those are objects, not arrays. As such, the order [**is not guaranteed**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/2341603), and does not matter. You would need to loop over the keys for each to find out if they are equal.

Comment: _asked many times_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: _"The function I am writing should have these two objects equal true"_ Can you include what you have written at Question? What is the issue that you are having returning expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual), from Lodash, to perform deep comparison between objects:

```js
const obj1 = {
  name: 'Sam',
  age: 27,
  description: [{
    eyes: 'blue',
    hair: 'brown'
  }]
} 

const obj2 = {
  age: 27,
  name: 'Sam',
  description: [{
    hair: 'brown',
    eyes: 'blue'
  }]
}

console.log(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: An answer should not rely on a library that isn't mentioned or tagged in the OP.